# Compiler error screen.mainScreen is a static member of type 'Screen'

Tags: nativescript

Help!. Compiler returns error

> Property 'mainScreen' is a static member of type 'Screen'

i am trying to get heightDIPs but this.

Comment: Please, provide the related part of code with imports. However, I think @William Juan is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check where `Screen` is being imported from. I've had issues in the past where VS Code would auto import the wrong `Screen`.

```js
import { Screen } from '@nativescript/core';

// and the following should work
Screen.mainScreen.heightDIPs
```

Comment: I see, i am importing 'screen' with a small s.
Thanks it worked!